Reverse String in java
Unable to reverse string in java
Given  String is "chandan.rai"
Output string "nadnahc.iar"
please help me in writing java programme for this
String str= "chandan.rai";
String  rev="";
      System.out.print("Original word: ");
      System.out.println("chandan.rai"); //Example word
      
      char[] ch=str.toCharArray();
       
      for (int i=str.length()-1; i>0; i--)
      {
        rev=rev+str.charAt(i);
      }
      System.out.println("Reversed word: "+ rev);
    

not getting required output "nadnahc.iar"

The character at position 0 is a valid part of the word. for (int i = str.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) { and it could have been a one line call like System.out.println("Reversed word: " + new StringBuilder(str).reverse());

according given example, the input must first be split in words separated by '.'; each word reversed, and then joined. Functional equivalent: Pattern.compile("\\.").splitAsStream("chandan.rai").map(StringBuilder::new).map(StringBuilder::reverse).map(StringBuilder::toString).collect(joining("."))

@user85421 you can omit the .map(StringBuilder::toString) step. Simpler and more efficient…

Or maybe String reversed = new Scanner(s).useDelimiter("\\.").tokens().map(StringBuilder::new).map(StringBuilder::reverse).collect(Collectors.joining("."));

Or String reversed = Pattern.compile("[^.]+").matcher("chandan.rai") .replaceAll(mr -> new StringBuilder(mr.group()).reverse().toString());

I’m guessing you are not allowed to use regular expressions for this assignment.  You must write an additional loop that searches for a '.' character, then uses the index of that character to limit the index bounds when you perform your existing reversal loop (which must take place inside the other loop).  Use the indexOf method of String to search for '.' characters.

You just need to fix your code slightly. Namely, (1) split the string by "." and reverse each of the parts separately, and (2) when traversing the parts backward, make sure to use >= instead of >. For example,
Try
String input = "chandan.rai";
String[] parts = input.split("\\.");
String output = "";

for (int k = 0; k < parts.length; k++) {
  String part = parts[k];
  if (k != 0) {
    output += '.';
  }
  for (int i = part.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    output += part.charAt(i);
  }
}

System.out.println(output);


Output: nadnahc.iar

To suggest to OP what was the issue with their code and how to fix it. Also would like to point out that the other suggested responses are incorrect as the OP wants to reverse each sub-components of the string (separated by .)

Okay -- missed that

BTW assuming StringBuilder is allowed, it already has a reverse() method (otherwise there is no need/advantage of using the StringBuilder at all)

Good point. Revised solution to remove StringBuilder
